# SQL nested query (not exists)

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a table called train, which has the columns number, arrive_station, depart_station

I have populated this and would like to find trains that only serve Edinburgh (i.e., all
trains departing from a station only arrive to Edinburgh)
I would like to use a nested query and use the not exists operator.

So far I have tried..

```
SELECT depart_station
FROM train
WHERE arrive_station = "edinburgh" 
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT arrive_station
    FROM train
    WHERE arrive_station != "edinburgh"
  );
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to relate your nested query back to your outer query somehow so if number is train number you'd want to add aliases to your tables and add `AND t1.number = t2.number`.

```
SELECT  depart_station
FROM    train t1
WHERE   arrive_station = "edinburgh" 
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  arrive_station
            FROM    train t2
            WHERE   t2.arrive_station != "edinburgh"
            AND     t1.number = t2.number
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use the exists operator? Surely an OR would be enough:

```
select *
from train
where depart_station = 'Edinburgh' or arrive_station = 'Edinburgh';
```

?

Comment: He wants to avoid a route that is a triangle so it doesn't have any connections that go between cities that are not Edinburgh. Using a `NOT EXISTS` is correct here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are only interested in any train route that arrives in Edinburgh. So just do this:

```
SELECT * FROM train WHERE arrive_station = "Edinburgh"
```

Combining this with a 'NOT EXISTS' expression, which creates a table of other routes, is redundant; just drop that part.

Comment: Im looking for departure stations that only operate to Edinburgh and to no other stations
eg London -> Edinburgh, London -> Glasgow
however say Queensferry(a small train station)  would only have trains going to Edinburgh and those are the ones I am writing a query for.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
SELECT depart_station
FROM train
WHERE arrive_station = "edinburgh" 
AND depart_station NOT IN (
    SELECT depart_station
    FROM train
    WHERE arrive_station != "edinburgh" 
)
```

Check [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c47d0/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  depart_station
FROM    train t1
WHERE   arrive_station = "edinburgh" 
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  arrive_station
            FROM    train t2
            WHERE   t2.arrive_station != "edinburgh"
            AND     t1.number = t2.number
        );
```

Very amazing logic exist in the query. It could be solved as:

```
select depart_station from train order by depart_station
```

but there is a logic that I was facing and this solved my problem too. My problem was a little bit different but anyway, this really provided a signal.